# using a string to reference a struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm having troubles with a function in C using a string to reference a struct, the used code is included below

```
int Search_name (char nombre[],Nentrada user_number){
int result;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < user_number ;i++)
{
    char *temp;
    asprintf(&temp,"user%d",i);
    printf("%s \n",temp);
    result = strcmp(nombre,user1.Nombre);
}
if (result != 0)
{
    result = 1;
}
return result;}
```

The code is used in a function that is usposed to search for a string in the argument "nombre" of the struct "entrada", it works perfectly when i manually use the struct assignments "user1.Nombre, user2.Nombre..." nonetheless when I use the string temp (which switch between values user1,user2...) I keep receiving the error

> error: request for member 'Nombre' in something not a structure or union|

Therefore I would like to know how can I aumatically switch the struct without having the issue.

Comment: *it works perfectly when i manually use the struct assignments "user1.Nombre, user2.Nombre..."* What does that mean? How do you use that? In your code, there is no `user1` or `user2` at all.

Comment: I mean, when i switch the line `result = strcmp(nombre,user1.Nombre);` for `result = strcmp(nombre,temp.Nombre);` the struct is not working, nonetheless the value of temp is the string "user1" therefore I would like to know how can I use the string temp which is actually the string "user1" as a reference to the struct user 1, "user1 and user2 are structs defined outside the function,

Comment: If I get you right, you want to use the string where `temp` is pointing to, as a variable name? That is not possible in C.

Comment: Is there any other option to point to the struct while using the for? without writting all the variables manually?

Comment: You might use an array of these structs and use the number as index into that array.

Comment: You can pass in a getter function as function pointer.